# If someone deposits money into your account for you to keep can they cause you more money problems off of that or steal more than money from it?

Tags: banking, scams

I met this girl online.  We hit it off quick, and we want to meet later. Her story is a little weird, but some of it could be true.

Anyway she wanted me to get an account so her dad could send her some money, and she was gonna give me some. I never asked for money, and didn't want it, but she didn't ask to send her any back or anything of the sort it was gonna be for me.  It just sounds funny, because she says its the only way her dad could trust someone if they didn't run off with the money.

Comment: "but some of it could be true". Unlikely.

Comment: "On the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog."  Or a man pretending to be a girl.

Answer (score 18):

It's a scam.

It's your account, you are responsible for it. She will send money from some illegal source, like a hacked bank account, or a stolen check. The money appears in your account, say $1,000. You return some part of it to her, say $500.

A month later the bank figures out that there was something wrong with the $1,000 and removes it. Now your account is at -$500. And the bank will make you pay that. Congratulations.

Meanwhile, that fat 40 year old bloke who pretended to be a girl to you is doing the same to a dozen other victims.

Comment: Ok thanks thought so just wanted to be sure

Comment: @Stevenpearson Basically: a stranger will never give you more than a dollar worth of money with good intentions in mind. Everyone is a stranger until you've actually met them, even then you need to be careful. There's nothing wrong with trusting, but always verify. A web chat is not a verification, a picture is not a verification and a phone call is not a verification. If a person can not be arsed to meet you, or be verified through trustworthy sources, before asking you for help or offering to help you, then they are not worth your time.

Answer (score 3):

> so her dad could send her some money

One word: PayPal.

Another word: Zelle.

Yet another word: Xoom.

A fourth word(s): Western Union.

Comment: I got it i blocked reported it

Comment: 5th: Venmo. 6th: Facebook. 7th: Google

Comment: 8th:  Her own darned bank account